# scatter plot of grouped time series frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I've got a frame df where columns are ['date', 'float', 'int'] to simplify.
The dates and floats are not unique so I group them:

```
dd = df.groupby(['date', 'float']).sum()
```

Thing is, I need to resample the date index, which I have to do via

```
dd = dd.unstack().resample('B').last()
```

otherwise without unstacking it will drop a level.

Now what I'd like to do is plot a scatter of the frame with 'date' as x axis, 'float' as y axis, and 'int' as the size of the dots.
I'm struggling to achieve this with the frame I now have.
Maybe the pre-processing I do is the wrong kind and there's a cleaner way to achieve this.
Regards,

Comment: Can you provide some dummy data you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no need to `unstack`. You can do your `groupby` and `resample` while maintaining a dataframe in the long format via `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby(["date", "float"])\
  .sum()\
  .reset_index(-1)\
  .resample("B")\
  .last()
```

Afterwards, you can use the normal [`ax.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) method with the `s` argument which defines the size of the dots, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# mocking your dataframe
dates = pd.date_range(start="2017-10-10", periods=20)
values = np.random.random(20)
sizes = np.random.randint(1, 80, 20)

df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": dates, 
                   "values": values, 
                   "sizes": sizes})

# plot setup
fig,ax= plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 7)

# scatter
ax.scatter(x=df["dates"].values,
           y=df["values"].values, 
           s=df["sizes"].values)

# setting x axis bounds
ax.set_xlim((df["dates"].min(), df["dates"].max()))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I still need to work around the reindexing in general as there seems to lie the power of pandas!